# Is an allene or a conjugated diene formed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

If we dehydrate the following molecule, which hydrogen ($\ce{H1}$ or $\ce{H2}$) gets removed?

[image: dehydration]

The conclusion that I have drawn from the molecule: The carbon to which $\ce{H1}$ is attached is $\ce{sp2}$ hybridized which makes $\ce{H1}$ slightly more acidic than $\ce{H2}$.

Comment: I would go for the conjugated product .

Answer (score 2):

As the intermediate passes through an allylic carbocation which is fairly stable, it does not matter which H is 'more acidic' - the whole system is in equilibrium. The product you get is the thermodynamically most stable which will be a conjugated diene.